# How to add test cases to Product Backlog Items in the Product backlog

Tags: azure, testing, case, devops

I'm looking for a way to add test scenario's to Product Backlog Items, via the 'Boards - Backlog' view, instead from the 'Boards - Boards' view.

[Boards - Boards view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FsRy.png)

Here I can click 'add test' to add a test scenario.

[Boards - Backlog view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgqiU.png)

Here I don't have the ability to add a test scenario.

I'm looking for a way to make my tests, linked to the Product Backlog Items, but do it based per Epic. In the 'backlogs' view I have a clear overview of my epics and the Product Backlogs within the EPIC. I don't have this overview via the 'Boards - Boards view'.

Can someone help me on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, on the second screenshot, it should be hidden under the `Add Link` menu

UPDATE:
Confirmed, under the `Add Link` there is an option to either link an existing test case or create a new one

Comment: When using the 'add link' it doesn't show up on the ticket or in the backlog. Where does it show up? 

When using the 'boards - boards' (first screenshot), the test cases show up on the ticket itself.

Comment: You just go into the menu and select the Test Case type there https://snipboard.io/FrWSwO.jpg

Comment: I've added a test case. But where does it go? It doesn't show in the backlog. See my screenshots in following links. https://snipboard.io/nyNXs2.jpg https://snipboard.io/TMyFYd.jpg https://snipboard.io/SkEyzp.jpg

Comment: I feel like this is impossible directly in the Backlog section of Azure DevOps, but I've managed to create a Custom Query which solves this https://snipboard.io/rbnyi4.jpg. You can also create it using the three-dot button -> Create Query and then just modify the criteria mentioned in the section `Filters for linked work items `

Comment: Could you screenshot these settings for the query under 'filters for linked work items'. Doesn't work for me.